# RxSwift subscriptions after didBecomeActive

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I've written module based on RxSwift with Viewcontroller and ViewModel. ViewModel contains gesture's observers and images observables. Everything works well, except situation when application `didBecameActive` directly to mentioned module. Subscriptions of gestures don't work and `imageView` become blank.

They are set inside subscription to observable based on `BehaviorSubjects`, inside view:

```
    func subscribePhotos(observerable: Observable<[(Int, UIImage?)]>) {
        disposeBag = DisposeBag()
        observerable.subscribeOnNext { [weak self] array in
            array.forEach { identifier, image in
                if let pictureView = self?.subviews.first(where: { view -> Bool in
                    guard let view = view as? PictureView else {
                        return false
                    }
                    return view.identifier == identifier
                }) as? PictureView {
                    pictureView.set(image)
                }
            }
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
     }
```

In viewModel I set `Observable`:

```
var imagesObservable: Observable<[(Int, UIImage?)]> {
    do {
        let collection = try photosSubject.value()
        if let photosObservables = collectionCreator?.getPhotosDetailsObservables(identifiers: collection.photoIdentifiers) {
            let photosObservable = Observable.combineLatest(photosObservables)
            return Observable.combineLatest(photosSubject, photosObservable,
                                            resultSelector: { collection, currentArray -> [(Int, UIImage?)] in
                var newArray = [(Int, UIImage?)]()
                currentArray.forEach { stringIdentifier, image in
                    if let picture = grid.pictures.first(where: { $0. stringIdentifier == stringIdentifier }) {
                        newArray.append((picture.identifier, image))
                    }
                }
                return newArray
            })
        }
    } catch { }
    return Observable<[(Int, UIImage?)]>.never()
}
```

}

`photosSubject` is initialized in viewModel's init

```
        photosSubject = BehaviorSubject<PictureCollection>(value: collection)
```

photosObservale

```
    func createImageObservableForAsset(asset: PHAsset, size: CGSize) -> Observable<UIImage?> {
        return Observable.create { obs in

            PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset,
                                                  targetSize: size,
                                                  contentMode: .aspectFit,
                                                  options: nil,
                                                  resultHandler: { image, _ in
                                                    obs.onNext(image)
            })

            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
```

And in ViewController I connect them by calling method of view:

```
        myView.pictureView.subscribePhotos(observerable: viewModel.imagesObservable)
```

After `didBecameActive` `pictureView`'s property image of type `UIImage` isn't nil, but they disappear. I could listen notification `didBecameActive` and invoke `onNext` on observer, but I’m not sure is it correct way to figure out problem.  Any idea what's reason of that?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved out this issue. Reason wasn't connected with Rx. Method drawing pictures draw(_:CGRect) was called after didBecomeActive and cleared myView. I changed method's body and now everything works well :)